# Help with putting RDF in a web page (jsp)

Tags: html, xml, jsp, rdf

When I read the documentation on Common-Tags, I thought it would be easy to put this in a jsp because the examples were cut and paste

```
<body xmlns:ctag="http://commontag.org/ns#" rel="ctag:tagged">
   <span typeof="ctag:Tag" 
         rel="ctag:means" 
         resource="http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/en.u2" 
         property="ctag:label" content="U2"/>
    </span>
</body>
```

It's a good thing that we're using Eclipse in our dev work. It's telling us that something is wrong with our markup. It's underlining the common-tags markup with yellow returning:

```
Undefined attribute name
```

What am I missing here? or is this completely okay?

Comment: You have a well-formedness error in your example. The span tag is closed twice (first with the `/>` and then again with `</span>`).

Answer (score 1):

The **typeof**, **resource** and **property** attributes are extensions to XHTML which are part of the RDFa specification which is why Eclipse doesn't know about them.

Since RDFa+XHTML is now a W3C recommendation this is absolutely fine to use as is.

http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-syntax/#rdfa-attributes

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're not sending your pages with an XML MIME type, because that snippet isn't well-formed. Using RDFa isn't allowed when using a text/html MIME type. For an alternative, have a look at ["microdata"](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/microdata.html).

Comment: Yes, a *proposal*. I personally don't like it at all.